# How to call asynchronous function in a synchronous function?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I want data from *async* function to return as a list which will be assigned a list inside the synchronous function. I am calling an asynchronous function in an OnCreateView method of Fragment in xamarin android, which is returning a list. When *async* method go and fetch the data it goes into a wait mode. When it is waiting for data return it comes out of function and read below code lines of synchronous method where it is called. When *async* function is not able to a return list. It is causing empty list on my activity and showing no data.

Here is My Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using OSDAMobileModel;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace OSDAMobileApp
{
    public class CheckInFragment : Fragment
    {
        List<Route> lstRoute = new List<Route>();
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);


        }

        public  override View  OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SelectRoute, container, false);
            ListView routesListView = view.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.ListView);
            List<Route> routeslst = lstRoute;
             OnAppearing();

            routesListView.Adapter = new CustomListAdapter(lstRoute);         


          return view;
        }


        protected async Task<List<Route>> OnAppearing()
        //protected  List<Route> OnAppearing()
        {
            SetupFiles setupFiles = new SetupFiles();
            //PRPMaster prpMaster = new PRPMaster();
            var prpDetails = await setupFiles.LoadTextAsync("PRPDetails.txt");

            PRPMaster prpMaster = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PRPMaster>(prpDetails);

            foreach (var item in prpMaster.PRPDetails)
            {
                lstRoute.Add(item.Route);
            }
           return lstRoute;

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to modify your list in your `async` function directly and then notify the changes to the adapter by calling:

`RunOnUiThread(() => routesListView.Adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged());`

Btw you call the `OnAppearing` like `Task.Run(() => OnAppearing());`

So it will end up like:

```
ListView routesListView;
List<Route> lstRoute = new List<Route>();

...

public  override View  OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SelectRoute, container, false);
    routesListView = view.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.ListView);

    routesListView.Adapter = new CustomListAdapter(lstRoute);         

    Task.Run(() => OnAppearing());

    return view;
}

...

protected async Task OnAppearing()
{
    SetupFiles setupFiles = new SetupFiles();
    //PRPMaster prpMaster = new PRPMaster();
    var prpDetails = await setupFiles.LoadTextAsync("PRPDetails.txt");

    PRPMaster prpMaster = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PRPMaster>(prpDetails);

    foreach (var item in prpMaster.PRPDetails)
    {
        lstRoute.Add(item.Route);
    }

    // This is necessary for the adapter to update its data
    RunOnUiThread(() => routesListView.Adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged());
}
```

HIH

Comment: which part? does it not update the list? does it throw an error? are you sure you are updating the same list you are passing to the adapter and notifying the data set changed on the UI thread? can you update your question with the code of your `CustomListAdapter`?